# Split and pivot key-value into rows using Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I'd like to extract just the keys (from a key-value pair) from a column into each own separate row. I attempted the split and pivot in Tableau to solve this. However, the "pivot" feature is not showing after the "split". How do we solve this just using Tableau desktop (not Tableau Prep)?

[view sample table and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlabG.png)